# Filter records using ajax jquery and php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I want to filter my search results based on some parameters using **checkboxes**.I have a search function alongwith pagination working,but all written in PHP.Now I want to filter the records,but this will need ajax requests and jquery probably and I am not good at it.Something similar done here http://www.proptiger.com/property-in-pune-real-estate.php The left panel has checkboxes to filter data.
This is the div which holds the search query and displays results.

```
           <div class="flt width710" id="displayProp">
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flt mapnewalert"> <?php //echo ucfirst($_SESSION['$cityName']) ?></div>
            <div style="float:right" id="toppagesel">
            <?php   

    /*****************Query for taking the count of the values of search criteria *********************** */
                        $countQuery = "Select count(*) as total from properties inner join cities on properties.city_id=cities.city_id inner join locality on properties.locality_id=locality.locality_id inner join properties_type on properties.property_id=properties_type.property_id where (cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' and locality.locality_name like '%".$_SESSION['$localityName']."%') or (property_price_min between '".$_SESSION['$minPrice']."' and '".$_SESSION['$maxPrice']."') or (property_price_max between '".$_SESSION['$minPrice']."' and '".$_SESSION['$maxPrice']."') or properties_type.bed_type='".$_SESSION['$bedType']."' ";
                        //print_r($countQuery);
                        $result1 = mysql_query($countQuery);
                        //echo($result1[0]);
                        $queryCount = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
                        //print_r($queryCount);
                        //echo($result1[total]);
                        //exit;
                        $pages->items_total = $queryCount[0];
                        //echo ($pages->items_total);
                        $pages->mid_range = 2;

                        $pages->paginate();
                        echo $pages->display_pages();       
                        echo $pages->display_items_per_page();

                        $query = "SELECT * from properties inner join cities on properties.city_id=cities.city_id inner join locality on properties.locality_id=locality.locality_id inner join properties_type on properties.property_id=properties_type.property_id where (cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' and locality.locality_name like '%".$_SESSION['$localityName']."%') or (property_price_min between '".$_SESSION['$minPrice']."' and '".$_SESSION['$maxPrice']."') or (property_price_max between '".$_SESSION['$minPrice']."' and '".$_SESSION['$maxPrice']."') or (properties_type.bed_type='".$_SESSION['$bedType']."') $pages->limit";

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            //}
            //echo $query;  
            //$getProperty =    $propertyDetails->getPropertyDetailsByCityIdPaginate($_SESSION['$cityId'],$limit);
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I understand I would have to write a **js function on check** of the checkbox,and pass the parameter to a .php page and process a query to return result,but not sure how to do it and **replace the current records** in the above  with the filtered records along with pagination.
This is my pagination class for reference

```
class Paginator{
var $items_per_page;
var $items_total;
var $current_page;
var $num_pages;
var $mid_range;
var $low;
var $limit;
var $return;
var $default_ipp;
//var $querystring;
var $ipp_array;

function Paginator()
{
    $this->current_page = 1;
    $this->mid_range = 2;
    $this->ipp_array = array(2,4,6,8,10,'All');
    $this->items_per_page = (!empty($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;
}

function paginate()
{
    if(!isset($this->default_ipp)) $this->default_ipp='8';
    if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
    {
        $this->num_pages = 1;
       //$this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
    }
    $this->current_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ; // must be numeric > 0
    $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
    $next_page = $this->current_page+1;
    if($_GET)
    {
        $args = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        foreach($args as $arg)
        {
            $keyval = explode("=",$arg);
            if($keyval[0] != "page" And $keyval[0] != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&" . $arg;
        }
    }

    if($_POST)
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
        {
            if($key != "page" And $key != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&$key=$val";
        }
    }
    if($this->num_pages > 4)
    {
        $this->return = ($this->current_page > 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$prev_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">&laquo; Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&laquo; Previous</span> ";

        $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
        $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

        if($this->start_range <= 0)
        {
            $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
            $this->start_range = 1;
        }
        if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)
        {
            $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
            $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
        }
        $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
            // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
            if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))
            {
                $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
            }
            if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
        }
        $this->return .= (($this->current_page < $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All') And $this->current_page > 0) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">Next &raquo;</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&raquo; Next</span>\n";
        $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    else
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
        }
        $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    $this->low = ($this->current_page <= 0) ? 0:($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
    if($this->current_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = 0;
    $this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";
}
function display_items_per_page()
{
    $items = '';
    if(!isset($_GET[ipp])) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
    foreach($this->ipp_array as $ipp_opt) $items .= ($ipp_opt == $this->items_per_page) ? "<option selected value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n":"<option value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n";
    return "<span class=\"paginate\">Items per page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'$this->querystring';return false\">$items</select>\n";
}
function display_jump_menu()
{
    for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
    {
        $option .= ($i==$this->current_page) ? "<option value=\"$i\" selected>$i</option>\n":"<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
    }
    return "<span class=\"paginate\">Page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring';return false\">$option</select>\n";
}
function display_pages()
{
    return $this->return;
}
```

}

How can achieve the filter part in my scenario??Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
**process.php**

```
    <?php session_start();

    include_once("includes/classes/db_connect.php");
    include_once("pagination/paginator.class.php");

    $value = $_POST['check']; 
    echo $value;

    $sql="SELECT * from properties inner join cities on properties.city_id=cities.city_id inner join suburbs on properties.suburb_id=suburbs.suburb_id where (cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' and suburbs.suburb_name like '%".$value."%')  $pages->limit";

    echo $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    //$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    /*echo "<pre>" ;
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>" ; */
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
            ?>
          <div class="projectlisttiger">        

        <div class="spacer5">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="listnewimg flt">
                        <a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php">
                            <!--<img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo ($row['property_cover_image']) ?>" width="186" height="125" border="0">
                            <img src="admin/uploads/Cilantra1/1cilantra-large.jpg" width="186" height="125" border="0">-->
                        </a>
                         <div class="newlistlaunch"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><img width="65" height="65" border="0" src="images/projects/kolte-patil/cilantra/new_launch_blue.png"></a>
                         </div>                             
                    </div>

                    <div class="listright">
                        <div style="width:498px; height:42px;" class="flt">
                            <div class="list-logo flt">
                                <div class="buildborder"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><img width="80" height="36" border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Kolte Patil" src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $row['builder_logo']?>"></a>
                                </div>
                                   <div class="tablistname"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><?php echo $row['property_name'] ?></a></div>
                            </div>   
                            <?php if ($row['property_price_min']!=0) { ?>      
                            <div class="listprice">
                                <img width="18" height="18" align="absmiddle" src="images/city/rupee_icon.gif"> <?php echo $row['property_price_min'] ?> Lacs - <?php echo $row['property_price_max'] ?> Lacs       
                            </div>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <div class="listprice">
                                 <img width="18" height="18" align="absmiddle" src="images/city/rupee_icon.gif">Price on Request
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </div>

                            <div class="spacer3">&nbsp;</div>        

                        <div class="listbox">
                            <a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><strong>Address</strong>:<?php echo $row['locality_name'] ?>, <?php echo $row['city_name'] ?><br> <strong>Types</strong>: 2BHK &amp; 3BHK
                            <br><strong>Sizes:</strong> <?php echo $row['property_size_min'] ?> sqft - <?php echo $row['property_size_max'] ?> sqft </a>
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-left:-3px;" class="flt">
                            <div style="width:110px;" class="flt"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><input type="button" value="View Details" class="detail_project"></a>
                            </div>     
                          <div style="width:110px;" class="flt"><input type="button" onClick="showEnqForm('2659','Cilantro'); return false;" value="Enquire Now" class="enquire_project"></div>
                        </div>
                               <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>                                 
                    </div>
                    <div class="spacer15">&nbsp;</div>              
           </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

EDIT::Resolved the display part by using this in the js file

```
       function changeResults(){
        var data = { 'venue[]' : []};
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
            var chck1 = $(this).val();
        //alert(chck1);
        data['venue[]'].push($(this).val());        
    });

 $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : 'process.php',
  data : data,
  success : function(data){
      $('#project_section').html(data); // replace the contents coming from php file
        }  
    });
}
```

But my pagination just doesn't work as it is in php.I have added paginator class.How can i fix this for the pagination to work with the response also.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use onchange event of javascript on checkbox and call function here is the function

```
function changeResults(){
    // Now get the values of checkbox
    var chk1 = $('#checkbox1').val(); // checkbox1 is id of checkbox
    $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : 'process.php';
     data : 'check='+chk1,
     success : function(data){
          $('#data-div').html(data); // replace the contents coming from php file
     }  
    });
}
```

seperate your php file

```
$value = $_POST['check'];
```

And now put this $value in your query in condition

Comment: Hi @raheel and thanks for the reply.I tried it and get the response to the query,but my problem is,the div is not replaced with the new one.The old content is still present on the page,how can I remove it?One more thing is,do I need to format the html in process.php itself??and return it in the same format as the current div element(that is to be replaced) has?

Comment: ofcourse you will have to also echo the formatted html so it will be available in jquery ajax function as data

Comment: I have done that.I have added my process.php in the question as an edit.The previous content of the div is present even after I echo the formatted content.

Comment: put all the divs in a php variable and echo $var it

Comment: do you mean that **data** in the js function will be the $var that will be echoed ??If I am understanding you correctly!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12197/discussion-between-sachin-taware-and-raheel-shan)

Comment: Hey thanks for your help till now.I have resolved atleast the displaying of records issue.Now I am having pagination issue.I am using PHP pagination and sending the paginated parameters back with the html response data.But when I click on the page number,it brings me to the process.php page.I want the pagination to occur on the same page(where response is sent).Is there a way that I can modify my current class of pagination to a ajax type of pagination and then handle all this at client side??This is troubling me a lot.I have added the pagination class for reference.Thanks